# How to reference a button name so VBA knows which columns to hide

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with 100 columns and I want to show only certain columns based on the button (Form Controls) that is clicked.

There is a matrix of the button names and the corresponding columns that should be shown on a separate sheet.

I think I need to identify the button that is clicked, use the button name to find the corresponding cell on the reference sheet, and then hide the columns by looping through each column that should be hidden.

For example, if the button named 'Variances' is clicked then I want to reference the variances row and shows columns 1,2,3,4,5,6,16

![Matrix showing the button names and columns to hide] https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-gDxLsmXP_IWmVHZVlCa005a0U

I could code statically for each button but I want to be able to add buttons without having to change the VBA code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

- Sam

Comment: Do a find or application.Match on the name of the button, then iterate through the columns hiding the columns on the other sheet using the index number.

Comment: Do a `case` statement on button clicked?

Comment: If the buttons are on a worksheet then `Application.Caller` will give the name of the button which was clicked: you would set all of the buttons' `OnAction` properties to point to the same Sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image below shows the setup for my excel sheet.

[image: Excel Setup]

As Tim Williams suggested, both buttons call Handler.

```
Sub Handler()

Dim row, column As Integer
Dim button As String

    button = Application.Caller
    For i = 2 To 3
        If Cells(i, 6).Value = button Then
            row = i
        End If
    Next
    For j = 7 To 8
        column = Cells(row, j).Value
        columns(column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you replicate my setup? Also, I believe VBA is case sensitive, so it should be 'button = Application.Caller'

Comment: Replicated your sheet and code and I am now getting a run time 1004 application-defined or object-defined error at the line 'column = Cells(row, j).Value'

Comment: What are the values for row and j?

Comment: Ahhh  replication error,it was looking at the wrong column. I should prolly go find some coffee... Thanks!

Comment: No worries. If I have resolved your problem, please mark my solution as the answer.